DYMO Label Connect JavaScript Library - Barcode issue
I am using the Dymo connect SDK to print labels from our web application.
The customers are designing their labels in the Dymoconnect software (.dymo files) and upload it to our software.
All was working fine but one of our customers started using the barcode object.
It renders fine in print preview, but seems like it's warped so how as the barcode reader will not read it. If we print directly from Dymoconnect it works fine.
This is an example of how it's rendered, top is using the SDK, bottom is from the software:
https://i.sstatic.net/M2q7lgpB.png
I thought it might be related to one of the renderParamsXml options, but all documentation points to broken links...
